# "AdMob" and "UIViews" in SceneKit framework

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, admob, scenekit

This may seem obvious for those of you who make games on a regular basis but does anyone know how I might add a `UIView` for my `AdMob` banner, this is my code (in my didMove):

```
let banner = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: self.frame.height - 50, 
                                  y: self.frame.width / 2 - 160, 
                              width: 320, 
                             height: 50))

banner.backgroundColor = .red
self.view?.addSubview(banner)
```

Any ideas?